# GHC cannot find dynamic libraries - Could not find module ‘Data.Functor.Reverse’

Tags: haskell, ghc, ghci

GHCi-7.8.4 will not load anything from `transformers` library as it cannot find the GHCi file. What is wrong?

```
Prelude> import Data.Functor.Reverse

<no location info>:
    Could not find module ‘Data.Functor.Reverse’
    Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for package ‘transformers-0.4.3.0’?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.

Locations searched:
  /home/jdm/.cabal/lib/transformers-0.4.3.0/ghc-7.8.4/Data/Functor/Reverse.dyn_hi
```

Comment: Why the `dynamic-typing` tag?

Answer (score 1):

https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2009-December/071442.html

> Use the `--enable-shared` option to cabal install.
>
> If you want dynamic
>   libraries everywhere, put `shared: True` in `~/.cabal/config`. You'll need
>   to recompile all of your libraries.